# Потоки и коллекции

Tags: java

Интересует такой вопрос: имеется поток в нем определенна коллекция, есть несколько потоков которые совершают некие действие, необходимо с потоков данные добавлять в коллекцию при этом у потоков не будет состояния TERMINATED пока программа работает.Как реализовать данную кухню.Можно ли использовать в таком случае static cылку на коллекцию?

```
class classname
static Map map;
class job1
thread1-> { .... classname.map.add(...)....}
class job1
thread2-> { .... classname.map.add(...)....}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно статическую ссылку на экземпляр map, а можно передавать экземпляр map непосредственно в иcполняющуюся в потоке задачу. Но я бы избегал статических переменных без реальной на то необходимости.

В данном случае куда важнее то, что доступ к map должен быть синхронизирован либо в критической секции внутри исполняемой задачи (важно выполнять синхронизацию по одному и тому же монитору), либо за счет правильно выбранной реализации map (например ConcurrentHashMap).

Конкретный подход зависит от выполняемой логики в потоках.

Comment: Еще вопрос:надо ли блочить коллекцию во время интрации элементов?По логике если коллекцию изменит другой поток будит ошибка или нет?

Comment: В общем случае, когда речь идет о модификации разделяемых данных, доступ всегда должен быть синхронизирован. В конкретном случае многое зависит от логики и конкретной реализации.

Answer (score -1):

Лучше использовать очередь в многопоточных приложениях
private BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();

В поток будете передовать ссылку на обьект, читается обьект queue.remove() или queue.poll() - оба метода удаляют из очереди элемент
String test = queue.poll(); // очередь уменьшиться.

Что бы небло колизий при одновременном доступе к очереди нескольких потоков необходимо сделать  synchronized (queue) { тут выполняем действия }

при синхронизации, одновременно очередь смогут читать только один поток.

Comment: Что значит лучше? Лучше для чего? Очередь и коллекции другого типа инструменты, которые подходят для конкретных случаев. Ни кто из них не лучше и не хуже.

Comment: Решил данную задачу путем копирования в локальную коллекцию, в моем случае коллекцию блокировать не совсем подходит ибо итератор может не скоро закончить .